# Difference between '>>' and '>' in Perl

Tags: perl, file-handling

What is the difference between these two code snippets?

1. `open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt');`
2. `open (MYFILE, '>data.txt');`

Comment: Also note that the 3-argument form of open, along with the use of lexical file handles, is generally recommended. In other words, use a scalar variable, rather than something like `MYFILE`, for your file handle. For example: `open(my $file_handle, '>', 'output.txt') or die $!`.

Comment: This really isn't "in Perl". Perl just continues the *NIX idiom.

Comment: Is this homework?  You could have found the answer simply by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. **`open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt')`** — Open `data.txt`, keep the original data, append data from the end.
2. **`open (MYFILE, '>data.txt')`** — Open `data.txt`, delete everything inside, and write data from the start.

---

From [`perldoc -f open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> If MODE is `'<'` or nothing, the file is opened for input. If MODE is `'>'`, the file is truncated and opened for output, being created if necessary. If MODE is `'>>'`, the file is opened for appending, again being created if necessary.

It stems from the shell usage that,

- `cmd < file.txt` to copy file into stdin,
- `cmd > file.txt` to write stdout into a file, and
- `cmd >> file.txt` to append stdout to the end of the file.

Comment: @mirod: `open(MYFILE, '>data.txt')` is equivalent to `open(MYFILE, '>', 'data.txt')`. Please read the link.